# jsp file comment entries redirects page

Tags: jsp

Im new to JSP and when I run the below file, the page redirects to date.jsp, even though that line is part of comment entry..

Not sure what is wrong here...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Using JavaBeans in JS2</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h2>Using JavaBeans in JSP1</h2>
<% response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1 
 response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0 
 response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0); //prevents caching at the proxy server  
%>
<!--
<jsp:forward page="date.jsp"/> 
<jsp:useBean id="test" class="action.TestBean" />

<jsp:setProperty name="test" 
                    property="message" 
                    value="Hello JSP..." />

<p>Got message....</p>

<jsp:getProperty name="test" property="message" />
 -->
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the `jsp:forward` is evaluated server-side, before the resulting HTML gets sent to the client. The client sees `date.jsp`, but never the HTML comments generated by the original JSP.

To solve this, put JSP comments around that part to "comment out" the jsp directive instead of HTML comments:

```
<%-- Comment --%>
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for a comment in JSP is:

```
<%-- comment --%>
```

Here is a [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_syntax.htm)

Answer (score 0):

It's because of this tag.

```
<jsp:forward page="date.jsp"/>
```

You cannot comment jsp tags like you comment html. This is the standard syntax for commenting tags.

```
<%-- Comment --%>
```